# How to replace . in patterned strings with / in Visual Studio

Tags: regex, visual-studio, editor

I have lot of code in our solution like this:

```
Localization.Current.GetString("abc.def.gih.klm");
```

I want to replace it with:

```
Localization.Current.GetString("/abc/def/gih/klm");
```

the number of dots (.) is variable.

How can I do this in Visual Studio (2010)?

Edit: I want to replace strings in code (in VS 2010 editor), not when I run my application

Thank you very much

Comment: Can't you just use `Shift` + `Ctrl` + `H` to do a Solution-wide search and replace? It supports regular expressions.

Comment: the problem is, I don't know how to use regex in this case

Comment: the regex for identifying your line would be something like `^Localization\.Current\.GetString\("(?:[\w]+\.)+[\w]+"\);$` but not sure how to do it in VS since i do not use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Misread your request.

If you press ctrl+shift h and put this as your find string

```
{Localization\.Current\.GetString\("[A-Za-z\/]+}(\.)
```

Then put this as your replace with:

```
\1/
```

And then in find options tick use regular expressions.

This will find the first dot and replace it. Clicking find next will get the second one etc. You will have to keep doing a replace all until they are all done. Someone can probably improve that!

As shown below

[image]

Comment: Using "blah" in an answer like this is not helpful. I have no idea what you are trying to say.

Comment: It was unhelpful, and more importantly incorrect anyway :-) Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the "Replace in Files" Dialogue with "Use Regular expressions"

Find what:

```
 {[^"]*"[^"]*}\.
```

If you want to be a bit more strict on the allowed characters between the quotes then try this

```
{[^"]*"[A-Za-z.]*}\.
```

this would allow only ASCII characters and dots between the quotes.

Replace with

```
\1/
```

It will find the first `"` in a row and replace the last dot before the next `"` with `/`

The problem is, it replaces only the last occurrence of a dot within the first set of `""` in each row. So you would have to call this a few times until you get the message "The text was not found"

And be careful if there is a wanted dot between `""`. it will be replaced also.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

you can't use this in visual studio as it has its [own flavour of regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx), not the one used in the .NET regex classes, and I don't think you can do lookbehind with it.

you can use this regex:

```
(?<=\("[\w.]+)\.
```

in the find and replace, replacing by .

Breaking it down:

- Match a dot (the . at the end)
- Which is preceeded by ([positive look behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)) a bracket ( followed by a " and then any number of characters which are letters or a dot (dots don't need to be escaped in a group)

if you are sure that the text that you want to replace only ever has the `Localization.Current.GetString` bit then you could include that in the lookbehind of the regex:

```
(?<=Localization\.Current\.GetString\("[\w.]+)\.
```